# How to neatly match "x" and "[x]" with a regex without repeating?

Tags: regex, perl, readability

I'm writing a Perl regex to match both the strings `x bla` and `[x] bla`. One alternative is `/(?:x|\[x\]) bla/`. This isn't desirable, because in the real world, `x` is more complicated, so I want to avoid repeating it.

The best solution so far is putting `x` in a variable and pre-compiling the regex:

```
my $x = 'x';
my $re = qr/(?:$x|\[$x\]) bla/o;
```

Is there a neater solution? In this case, readability is more important than performance.

Comment: Incidentally, `qr//o` doesn't mean anything :)

Comment: @hobbs: I just read through perlop again, and you're right (except if `$x` would change). Thanks!

Comment: I think your solution is fine (you might compile `$x=qr/x/` as I now see robert already mentioned), also, while I can't find it right   now I have read several times that `/o` isn't needed anymore. I would ask our resident guru @tchrist for proof of that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible, but not all that clean. You can use the fact that conditional subpatterns support tests such as `(?(N))` to check that the Nth capturing subpattern successfully matched. So you can use an expression such as `/(\[)?X(?(1)\])/` to match '[X]' or 'X'.

Comment: I was looking for this, but couldn't quite dig up the right syntax. Yours beats mine :)

Comment: Nice idea. I think this is the neatest code I'm going to get :)

Comment: There's also a trick you can use for simpler regex flavours that don't support conditional subpatterns: `/(\[())?X(\2\])?/`. With this, an empty string is matched as \2 if the open bracket is present, which you can check for later.

Comment: Neat. If only it worked in all RE engines. (Some bind a subexpression to the empty string by default.)

Comment: The ECMAScript/JavaScript equivalent is `/(\[?)x(?:(?!.*$\1)\]|(?=.*$\1))/`

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-compile `$x` as well.  This also makes errors a little more obvious if `$x` is really `?(+[*{` or something else that a regex compiler will completely freak out on.

```
my $x = qr/x/;
my $re = qr/(?:$x|\[$x\]) bla/o;
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem, but I learnt something new. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a neater solution really, because this is where we leave the domain of regular languages and start requiring a more complex automaton with some kind of memory. (Backrefs would do it, except that the backref expands to a literal match against a preceding part of the string, not to “*this*, but only if *that* was matched”.)

Sometimes, it's possible to instead use a two step process, replacing a complex `X` with a single character known to not be present in the source text (control characters can be suitable for that) so allowing a simpler second-stage match. Not always possible though; depends on what you're matching.

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like `(\[)?x(??{ defined $1 ? "]" : "" })` but you probably shouldn't.

Comment: Heh, that's not neat :) Thanks for showing that it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the `/(\[)?X(?(1)\])/` solution (which garnered a score of 7), and it also matched `[X` and `X]`, which are incorrect.  The original poster's `/(?:$x|\[$x\]) bla/` actually works, requiring either matched brackets or none.

Comment: Did you forget to anchor the regex, so it matched the 'x' of '[x'? It works fine: `$ perl -E "say for grep { m/^(\[)?x(?(1)\])$/ } qw/x [x x] [x]/"`

Comment: Actually, it was @jaytea who forgot to anchor it.

Comment: To make it work properly unanchored you can just do `/(?:\[()|(?<!\[))x(?(1)\]|(?!\]))/`